# UILabel in UITableViewCell unexpectedly clipping

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell subclass, entirely in code (no xib/storyboard), which is just adding some text to be displayed like in a chat view.

It works fine, except that the last word is missing. It's apparently been truncated.

Changing the string changes where the clipping happens but it always seems to be the last line that's dropped.

The constraints look right to me.  Can anyone suggest what's wrong here?

```
class MessageCell : UITableViewCell {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let spacer = UIView()

        label.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0

        backgroundColor = .clear

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [spacer, label])
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = 0
        stackView.alignment = .trailing
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
            spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 1.0)
        ])
    }
}
```

Registered:

```
tableView.register(MessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "messageCell")
```

And returned:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell", for: indexPath)
}
```

Here's a screen shot of what I'm seeing (iOS 12 iPhoneX simulator):

[image]

Comment: As you posted, it works fine in a new project. But, I'm curious... why use a "spacer" view in a stack view? Why not simply constrain the label to the trailing edge, and constrain the width of the label to 80% of the contentView width -- `label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8)` ?

Comment: My understanding of stack views is that they are supposed to take care of the positioning constraints for you - putting a spacer on the label constraining it to something outside the label doesn't feel right to me.  Spacer feels cleaner.

Comment: Stack views are great for ***arranging*** multiple views. In your case, it doesn't really apply. Of course, there are multiple ways to get the layout you want, but simplicity is often a better approach. Here is the way I would do it: https://pastebin.com/TWW5RdcT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this does work fine in a standalone project but not in the project I'm working on.  I have not figured out why.  But I did figure out how to make this work:  By not using the stack view.

```
class MessageCell : UITableViewCell {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        label.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: -8),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -16),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])

        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0))
    }
}
```

I don't see any reason this should work when the other didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

method and try to increase the size the cell itself. Which I think causing the problem. Otherwise you can also use auto resizing cells. By the way use are using wrong reuse identifier(message instead of messageCell). I don't think that is causing the above problem though.

Comment: This is an auto resizing cell. The incorrect reuse identifier was a mistake I made preparing the StackOverflow post - I'll fix that - the code I was testing is correct.

I could fall back to calculating the size and returning it but I believe the way I'm doing it here should work, and would be much simpler than that.  Curious what's wrong.